# How to make this effect work if the window is resized when page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have an effect that makes the header become un-fixed when a specified div hits the top of the screen, and scroll with the rest of the content.

This works perfectly and i wrapped the "const targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top" in a resize event listener. But its calculations are wrong if the page is already scrolled and i have no idea why.

Another issue is that if the page is refreshed scrolled down, the header will be there until you scroll.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
    const targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(targetTopPos);
};

const headerEl = document.querySelector('header')
const targetEl = document.querySelector('#target')

const targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top

let isHeaderFixed = true

document.onscroll = () => {
  const targetTopOffset = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top
  
  if (isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset < 100) {
    headerEl.style.position = 'absolute'
    headerEl.style.top = `${targetTopPos - 100}px`
    isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
  }
  
  if (!isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset >= 100) {
    headerEl.style.position = 'fixed'
    headerEl.style.top = '0px'
    isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.target {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Custom header
</header>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
<div id="target" class="target">target</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
```

I write the "targetTopPos" to the console so you can see the issue

Comment: its really not, I give an example and explain what i want. The person below understands

Comment: the main issue is the resizing, you havent even touched on that. I understand how to run code on load, Its not calculating correctly, if you read the question you will se i have said that already

Answer (score 0):

It's because you redefine `targetTopPos` as a const in your `onresize` event.
You only have to asign the new value to `targetTopPos`

see code below

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
    targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(targetTopPos);
};

const headerEl = document.querySelector('header')
const targetEl = document.querySelector('#target')

let targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top

let isHeaderFixed = true

document.onscroll = () => {
  const targetTopOffset = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top
  
  if (isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset < 100) {
    headerEl.style.position = 'absolute'
    headerEl.style.top = `${targetTopPos - 100}px`
    isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
  }
  
  if (!isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset >= 100) {
    headerEl.style.position = 'fixed'
    headerEl.style.top = '0px'
    isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.target {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  Custom header
</header>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
<div id="target" class="target">target</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sébastien, thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. When the page is resized it works it out wrong

Comment: It works if the page is scrolled all the way to the top, but not if you are scrolled down at all

Comment: I got it to work by using "targetTopPos = targetEl.offsetTop + 100;" on resize, now i've just got to try and fix the on load issue

Comment: Great ! For the load issue maybe you can use something like that `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... })` or if you use jquery `$(document).ready`

Comment: I can't use a document loaded kind of event listener as i use PAJAX to load the content so i can have page transitions. I do have a listener for when the DOM has been replaced but it's still calculating wrong. I am working on it